# How to sync vue.js data to global javscript variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I am currently working on an application with `three.js` and `vue.js`.

When I click on the 3D model a function gets triggered where the name of the clicked part of the model is set in the variable *"name"* which then should be rendered by vue.js.

On `pageload` the `inital` value of *"name"* in this example *HELLO* gets rendered. But when I click on the model the variable *"name"* gets updated but not the data variable *"property"* in vue.js.

How do I get reactivity to this example ?

**JavaScript Part **:****

```
var name = "HELLO". //defined as global variable


[...]

// Handling of click event in three.js

if (intersects.length > 0) {for(i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
   if(intersects[ 0 ].object.name == 'K' + i ) { 
       //functions for specific parts are wrapped in an object to enable function call based on variable 'i'
      foo['K_' + i]('K' + i);         
}}

var foo = {
    K_1: function(i) {
         name = "foo_ " + i;
    },

    K_2: function() {},
    ...
}
```

**vue.js Part :**

```
const app = Vue.createApp ({
    data() {
        return {
            property: name // object key "property" is set to var "name"
        }
    },

template: 
    `<h1> {{ property }} </h1>`
})

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: It's unclear for me what you want to achieve ? Can you please elaborate the problem statement. How you want to update the `name` property in vue.js ?

Comment: @Creative Learner: There is a 3D model with different parts. By handling the on-click event the *name* of the clicked portion is returned and a specific function is called based on the *name*. In the specific function a variable is set to the *name* from the on-click event. This variable should be in-sync with vue.js so the *name* of the clicked portion is shown in the DOM. Is the problem statement more clear? - Based on that i would edit my quesetion so it is more useful for other users. 

The answer from tao do the trick to what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger vue's reactivity you have to use a `ref`:

```js
const { ref, createApp  } = Vue;
var name = ref("HELLO");

var foo = {
  K_1(i) {
    name.value = "foo_ " + i;
  },
};

//the vue app:

createApp ({
  setup: () => ({ property: name })
  template: `<h1> {{ property }} </h1>`
}).mount('#app')
```

Note: You can group multiple refs into one `reactive` object, to reduce the boilerplate:

```js
const { reactive, toRefs, createApp } = Vue;
const store = reactive({
  name: 'HELLO'
  someOtherProp: 'whatever',
  yetAnotherReactiveProp: null // you got the picture
})

var foo = {
  K_1(i) {
    store.name = "foo_ " + i;
    //      ☝️ no need for `.value` in `reactive`; only in `ref`
  },
  changeSomeOtherProp(val) {
    store.someOtherProp = val;
  }
}
createApp ({
  setup: () => ({ ...toRefs(store) })
  template: `<h1> {{ { name, someOtherProp, yetAnotherReactiveProp } }} </h1>`
}).mount('#app')
```